# scala split string by discarding for few

Tags: java, scala, split

Just want to find out what is the best way to split the following string into desired format.

```
123456_deploy_first_one_second_one_third_one....
```

desired format

```
123456
deploy
first_one
second_one
third_one
..
..
```

Know it's crazy. But one situation demands me to split to avoid lot of cycles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not a reasonable approach. it doesn't scale. You need to have a unique delimiter. You cannot split by a given delimiter just some times..

Answer (score 3):

Replace the sub-string that you want to preserve with a unique string that won't otherwise be found in the data string. Then `split()` and restore.

```
"123456_deploy_first_one_second_one_third_one"
  .replaceAll("_one",".")      //replace all targets with a marker
  .split("_")
  .map(_.replace(".","_one"))  //restore the target strings
//res0: Array[String] = Array(123456, deploy, first_one, second_one, third_one)
```

Comment: Very nice solution

Answer (score 2):

`Split` with `delimiter _` and after that you should combine them like below

```
val str="123456_deploy_first_one_second_one_third_one"
val splitArr=str.split("_")
val ans=splitArr.take(2).mkString("\n")+"\n"+splitArr.drop(2).grouped(2).map(_.mkString("_")).mkString("\n")
```